# (Wordpress) Redirection loop on homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-301

I have a issue with one membership page (Wordpress) I manage, which I just can´t resolve.

On the login page only, some customer have a redirection loop, which is permanent on the test site:  [test.app.neowake.de](https://test.app.neowake.de).

The login page has the page ID 301 (how ironic), so in the redirection loop you get send from test.app.neowake.de to test.app.neowake.de/index.php-page_id=301 - so to the same page.

I have tried everything from changing the Cache Plugin, clearing htaccess file and saving permalinks, checking url in DB, changing Theme, disabling plugins and canonical etc.

Contacting the support of the Theme, Caching plugin, membership plugin, etc. did not help, they just point the finger to the next one.

The wordpess installation is not in a subfolder.

The htaccess file contains this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# Die Anweisungen (Zeilen) zwischen „BEGIN WordPress“ und „END WordPress“ sind
# dynamisch generiert und sollten nur über WordPress-Filter geändert werden.
# Alle Änderungen an den Anweisungen zwischen diesen Markierungen werden überschrieben.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Is there anything I haven´t thought about? Or did anyone else have the same probleme?